# Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations runtime error

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, google-location-services

There are plenty of similar questions asked but none seem to solve my problem.

I have applied run time permissions as mentioned on the documentation, still I am getting a run time error on the line

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Here is my complete code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {

private static final String TAG ="hello" ;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


public Location mLastLocation=null;


public final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (mGoogleApiClient==null){
        mGoogleApiClient= new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)

                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 100)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval( 1* 100); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    }









@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {


    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager
            .PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionCheck1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);


        }
    }


    mLastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        TextView mLatitudeText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView mLongitudeText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

        Log.i("Location Info", "Location achieved!");

    } else {



        Log.i("Location Info", "No location :(");

    }


    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);//error here!!






}



@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onPause();
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION :{
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Log.i("Message","Got full permission");



            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }



}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    Log.i("Location Info", "Location is changed Bitchh :(");
    handleNewLocation(location);
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
}
```

}

Also I **have given** permission in the manifest file.

So, this is the error stack trace on run time

> 10-24 17:13:02.857 2224-2379/com.example.ashutosh.location E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>   0-24 17:13:03.184 2224-2224/com.example.ashutosh.location E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.example.ashutosh.location, PID: 2224
>                                                                                java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
>                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcda.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdd.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdj.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzccc.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbay.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbca.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcx.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcp.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzccb.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.example.ashutosh.location.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:122)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzn(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcp.zzm(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcd.zzpY(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcd.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcx.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbi.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzrj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzs(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzrk(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: I think you need remove runtime permission code from onConnected and try put before start on google api for location so google api for location not start until user allow location permission as you have asked runtime.

Comment: your code is running exactly after the runtime permission check if-else block. It doesn't wait for response from user input result.

Comment: Have a look at my library to handle runtime permissions easily. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: You try ask permission after connection is established but it crashes when you request location updates. Ask permission and if i's granted then request location.

Comment: @Krups I am very new to android. It may be silly but what code may i implement to wait for response?

Comment: @NabinBhandari I saw your code but I would really appreciate if you would help me here!

Comment: @AshutoshChapagain Please let me know if you were able to resolve and proceed since I'm also facing the similar problem after going through udacity google location service online course.

Answer (score 2):

`requestPermissions()` is *asynchronous*. When it returns, you do not yet have permission. The user has not even been *asked* about the permission.

You need to do your location logic in two places:

- Up front, if you have permission already
- In `onRequestPermissionResult()`, if you requested permissions and the user granted them

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Location/FusedNew) and [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Location/FusedPeriodic) illustrate how to request runtime permissions and use them with `LocationClient`.

Comment: I am  new to android and I can't get a bit of your github code. Can you explain in my own code?

Comment: If app don't have permission,
Put your location related code after user allow permission.
i.e.
Location services related code should be called from........ 


      if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Message","Got full permission");
// Call location related code from here
            }

Comment: What do you mean by upfront? The start of the app?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha: That is up to you. In the app shown in the question, the developer is trying to request location updates in `onCreate()` of an activity. That is the developer's decision. In general, if `checkSelfPermission()` indicates that you have permission, you do the work immediately; otherwise, you postpone the work until `onRequestPermissionResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sequence,

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
if (permissionCheck != PackageManager
        .PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionCheck1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);


    }
} else {

if (mGoogleApiClient==null){
    mGoogleApiClient= new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)

            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(10 * 100)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
        .setFastestInterval( 1* 100); // 1 second, in milliseconds
        }
}



@Override public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
mLastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
if (mLastLocation != null) {
    TextView mLatitudeText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView mLongitudeText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
    mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    Log.i("Location Info", "Location achieved!");
} else {
    Log.i("Location Info", "No location :(");
}

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);//error here!!
}


@Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION :{
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Message","Got full permission");
        if (mGoogleApiClient==null){
         mGoogleApiClient= new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
        }
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(10 * 100)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
        .setFastestInterval( 1* 100); // 1 second, in milliseconds
        } else {

            // permission denied, boo! Disable the
            // functionality that depends on this permission.
        }
        return;
    }
    // other 'case' lines to check for other
    // permissions this app might request
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it does not work. There is an error which say Call requires permission which may be rejected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I hate the following solution but I did not find any better.
If you request location API from Google API's and you do: `.addApi(LocationServices.API)`, you need to have location permitted before connecting GoogleAPI's.

Thus,

```
fun checkPermission(context:Context, permission:Name) : Boolean =
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

fun isLocationPermissionGranted() = checkPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

if (isLocationPermissionGranted()) {
     googleApiBuilder.connect()
} else {
     MyPermissionChangeRegistrar().instance.register { 
          if (isLocationPermissionGranted()) {
               googleApiBuilder.connect()
          }
     } 
}
```

When the Permission registrar is a class that calls a callback when a permission changed

```
class SomeActivity: Activity() {
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        MyPermissionChangeRegistrar.callCallbacks()
    }
}
```

IMMHO, Google ought to protect against such cases internally. But they don't.